# Correctly implementing the Swing TreeModel

Tags: java, thread-safety, tree, swing, event-handling

Ideally the Code Review would target the correctness of the approach implementing the Swing TreeModel.

In particular, is the structural separation[1], event message passing, threading[2], object synchronisation, etc. all best practice ?

- [1] My understanding is that the TreeModel should have separation between the underlying Tree Model and the object reports changes to the Swing JTree.
- [2] My understanding is that there should be separate threads for UI and Model changes.

In the interests of disclosure there is a bug that the UI doesn't show new child nodes once the parent node has been expanded in the UI.

Once any issues with the correctness of the approach are sorted, and if the bug still exits, assistance in this area would be appreciated.

[Full Runnable Package is on Github](https://github.com/xenomorpheus/MutableJTreeModel)

Aside: Please note I'm still pretty new to this Code Review site, Swing and Java.
I have read and tried to follow the question guidelines.

CLASS: Node - A Node in the Tree Model.

```
/** This document is AS-IS. No claims are made for suitability for any purpose. */
package com.example.mutablejtreemodel;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

/**
 * A node in a tree structure.
 * 
 * Nodes will fire change events to listeners which can be other nodes, or
 * JTreeModel objects.
 * 
 * @author xenomorpheus
 * @version $Revision: 1.0 $
 */
public class Node implements ActionListener {

/** class logger */
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Node.class.getName());

/** synchronisation lock */
private static final Object OBJ_LOCK = new Object();
// Read more:
// http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/synchronization-in-java-synchronized.html#ixzz2wy76gzSj

/** The human identifiable name of this node. */
private String name;

/** Our parent node. */
private Node parent;

/** The child nodes of this node. */
private List<Node> children;

/**
 * Those that listen for changes to the model. E.g. other nodes or
 * JTreeModel. Using weak references for listener set. It's very easy to
 * forget removing listeners when the actual instance isn't in use any more
 * and thats a source of memory leak.
 */
private Set<ActionListener> listeners;

/**
 * Constructor.
 * 
 * @param name
 *            the human identifiable name of this node.
 */
public Node(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    children = new ArrayList<>();
    listeners = Collections
            .newSetFromMap(new WeakHashMap<ActionListener, Boolean>(32,
                    0.75f));
}

/** Constructor. */
public Node() {
    this("No Name");
}


/**
 * Set the parent Node.
 * 
 * @param parent
 *            the new parent.
 */
public void setParent(Node parent) {
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}

/**
 * @return the parent node.
 */
public Node getParent() {
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        return parent;
    }
}

// Tree related methods.
/**
 * @return True only if the node has no children.
 */
public boolean isLeaf() {
    return false;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return The number of child nodes.
 */
public int getChildCount() {
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        return children.size();
    }
}

/**
 * Return the child node at this position.
 * 
 * @param index
 *            the position of the child node.
 * 
 * @return the child node at this position.
 */
public Node getChild(int index) {
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        Node child = children.get(index);
        LOGGER.info("At index=" + index + " found child named '"
                + child.name + "'");
        return child;
    }
}

/**
 * Return the position number this child node is at.
 * 
 * @param child
 *            the child node to look for.
 * 
 * @return the position number.
 */
public int getIndexOfChild(Node child) {
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        int index = children.indexOf(child);
        LOGGER.info("getIndexOfChild: In node '" + name + "' found child "
                + child.name + " at index " + index);
        return index;
    }
}

/**
 * Return true only if the node is one of our direct children.
 * 
 * @param node
 *            node we are looking for.
 * 
 * @return true only if found as a direct child of this object.
 */
public boolean isOurChild(Node node) {
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        return children.contains(node);
    }
}

/**
 * Add the child node to the end of a list of children nodes.
 * 
 * @param child
 *            new child node.
 */
public void add(Node child) {
    // Wrapped in sync to ensure size is still correct when add is called.
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        add(child, children.size());
    }
}

/**
 * Insert the child to the list of children nodes, at the point specified.
 * 
 * @param child
 *            new child node.
 * @param childCount
 *            insertion point.
 */
public void add(Node child, int childCount) {
    LOGGER.info("Parent='" + name + "', child='" + child + "' at index="
            + childCount);
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        // child node from current parent, if any.
        Node currentContainer = child.getParent();
        if (null != currentContainer) {
            currentContainer.remove(child);
        }
        // add child to children.
        children.add(childCount, child);

        child.setParent(this);

        // We listen for changes on nodes we hold.
        child.addActionListener(this);
        // We inform listeners that we have changed because we have a new
        // node.
        fireNodeChanged(new ActionEvent(child, childCount,
                NodeChangeType.NODE_INSERTED.toString()));
    }
}

/**
 * Remove one of our direct child nodes.
 * 
 * @param child
 *            the time to remove.
 */
public void remove(Node child) {
    LOGGER.info("remove node=" + this);
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        children.remove(child);
        child.setParent(null);

        // Stop listening to child node.
        child.removeActionListener(this);
    }
}

/**
 * @return a path of nodes leading up to the root node.
 */

public TreePath getPathToRoot() {
    Node node = this;
    ArrayList<Node> nodeArrayList = new ArrayList<Node>();
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        while ((null != node)) {
            nodeArrayList.add(node);
            node = node.getParent();
        }

        return new TreePath(nodeArrayList.toArray(new Node[nodeArrayList
                .size()]));
    }
}

/**
 * Notify Listeners that this node has changed in some way. e.g. this node
 * is about to be die.
 * 
 * @param e
 *            event.
 */
private void fireNodeChanged(ActionEvent e) {
    LOGGER.info("fireTreeNodeChanged node='" + this + "'");
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        for (ActionListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.actionPerformed(e);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Remove a listener from the list that wish to listen to events involving
 * this node.
 * 
 * @param listener
 *            listener to add.
 */
public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
    LOGGER.info("addActionListener for '" + this + "', listener='"
            + listener + "'");
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }
}

/**
 * Add a listener to the list that wish to listen to events involving this
 * node.
 * 
 * @param listener
 *            listener to remove.
 */
public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
    LOGGER.info("removeActionListener for '" + this + "', listener="
            + listener);
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }
}

// Misc. methods.

/**
 * Request the destruction of this node. Notify the listeners of this node
 * of the death.
 */
public void destroy() {
    ActionEvent event;
    LOGGER.info("destroy node=" + this);

    // Notify listeners this node is being destroyed.
    event = new ActionEvent(this, 0, NodeChangeType.NODE_REMOVED.toString());
    fireNodeChanged(event);
    // If parent still set, remove this node from parent.
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        if (null != parent) {
            parent.remove(this);
        }
    }
    // TODO free resources of this node at this subtype.
    // TODO call parent class's destroy.
}

/**
 * Perform actions when we are notified about an event. e.g. the death of
 * one of our child nodes.
 * 
 * @param e
 *            the event we have been informed about.
 * 
 * @see java.awt.event.ActionListener#actionPerformed(ActionEvent)
 */
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    LOGGER.info("actionPerformed, event=" + e.toString());
    String command = e.getActionCommand();
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (NodeChangeType.NODE_REMOVED.toString().equals(command)) {
        LOGGER.info(command + " event");
        if (source instanceof Node) {
            Node child = (Node) source;
            LOGGER.info("actionPerformed,  Source is node=" + child);
            synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
                if (children.contains(child)) {
                    LOGGER.info("actionPerformed,     '" + this
                            + "' removing child node called='" + child
                            + "'");
                    children.remove(child);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

CLASS: NodeJTreeModel - The Swing JTree will listen to and instance of this TreeModel to recieve notification of changes to the underlying Model ( of Node objects in a tree ).

```
/** This document is AS-IS. No claims are made for suitability for any purpose. */
package com.example.mutablejtreemodel;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.event.TreeModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

/**
 * Objects of this class form an adapter between a JTree and the model, that
 * being a tree of Node objects.
 * 
 * The methods in this class allow the JTree component to traverse the tree.
 * 
 * @author xenomorpheus
 * @version $Revision: 1.0 $
 **/
public class NodeJTreeModel implements TreeModel, ActionListener {

/** class logger */
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(NodeJTreeModel.class
        .getName());

/**
 * synchronisation lock.
 * http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/synchronization
 * -in-java-synchronized.html#ixzz2wy76gzSj
 */
private static final Object OBJ_LOCK = new Object();

/** We specify the root directory when we create the model. */
private Node root;

/**
 * Those that listen for changes to the model. Using weak references for
 * listener set. It's very easy to forget removing listeners when the actual
 * instance isn't in use any more and thats a source of memory leak.
 */
private Set<TreeModelListener> listeners;

/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public NodeJTreeModel() {
    listeners = Collections
            .newSetFromMap(new WeakHashMap<TreeModelListener,Boolean>(32, 0.75f));
}

// Getters and Setters

/**
 * The model knows how to return the root object of the tree.
 * 
 * @return Object
 * @see javax.swing.tree.TreeModel#getRoot()
 */
@Override
public Object getRoot() {
    return root;
}

/**
 * Set the root node.
 * 
 * @param root
 *            set the root node that this TreeModel is listening to.
 */
public void setRoot(Node root) {
    this.root = root;
    root.addActionListener(this);
}

// Misc methods
/**
 * Notifies the listener that the structure below a given node has been
 * completely changed.
 * 
 * @param path
 *            the sequence of nodes that lead up the tree to the root node.
 */
private void fireStructureChanged(TreePath path) {
    TreeModelEvent event = new TreeModelEvent(this, path);
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        for (TreeModelListener lis : listeners) {
            lis.treeStructureChanged(event);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Notifies the listener that some nodes have been removed below a node.
 * 
 * @param parentPath
 *            the sequence of nodes from the parent node to the root node.
 * @param indices
 * @param nodes
 */
private void fireNodesRemoved(TreePath parentPath, int[] indices,
        Object[] nodes) {
    TreeModelEvent event = new TreeModelEvent(this, parentPath, indices,
            nodes);
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        for (TreeModelListener lis : listeners) {
            lis.treeNodesRemoved(event);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Notifies the listener that a particular node has been removed.
 * 
 * @param path
 * @param index
 * @param node
 */
private void fireNodeRemoved(TreePath path, int index, Object node) {
    fireNodesRemoved(path, new int[] { index }, new Object[] { node });
}

/**
 * Notifies the listener that the appearance of some sub-nodes a node has
 * changed.
 * 
 * @param parentPath
 * @param indices
 * @param nodes
 */
private void fireNodesChanged(TreePath parentPath, int[] indices,
        Object[] nodes) {
    TreeModelEvent event = new TreeModelEvent(this, parentPath, indices,
            nodes);
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        for (TreeModelListener lis : listeners) {
            lis.treeNodesChanged(event);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Notifies the listener that the appearance of a node has changed.
 * 
 * @param parentPath
 *            the path of the parent node of the relevant node.
 * @param index
 *            the index of the node under the parent node. If <0, the
 *            listener will not be notified.
 * @param node
 *            the subnode.
 */
private void fireNodeChanged(TreePath parentPath, int index, Object node) {
    if (index >= 0) {
        fireNodesChanged(parentPath, new int[] { index },
                new Object[] { node });
    }
}

/**
 * Notifies listeners that below a node, some nodes were inserted.
 * 
 * @param parentPath
 *            TreePath
 * @param indices
 *            int[]
 * @param subNodes
 *            Object[]
 */
private void fireNodesInserted(TreePath parentPath, int[] indices,
        Object[] subNodes) {
    TreeModelEvent event = new TreeModelEvent(this, parentPath, indices,
            subNodes);
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        for (TreeModelListener lis : listeners) {
            lis.treeNodesInserted(event);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Notifies the listener that a node has been inserted.
 * 
 * @param parentPath
 * @param index
 * @param node
 */
private void fireNodeInserted(TreePath parentPath, int index, Object node) {
    fireNodesInserted(parentPath, new int[] { index },
            new Object[] { node });
}

/**
 * Method actionPerformed.
 * 
 * @param e
 *            ActionEvent
 * @see java.awt.event.ActionListener#actionPerformed(ActionEvent)
 */
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    NodeChangeType command = NodeChangeType.get(e.getActionCommand());
    int id = e.getID();
    LOGGER.info("actionPerformed was called: " + e);
    LOGGER.info("           source =" + source);
    LOGGER.info("           command =" + command);
    LOGGER.info("           ID =" + id);

    if (source instanceof Node) {
        Node node = (Node) source;
        LOGGER.info("command type: " + command);
        LOGGER.info("fire events: Node path to root" + node.getPathToRoot());

        switch (command) {

        case STRUCTURE_CHANGED:
            fireStructureChanged(node.getPathToRoot());
            break;

        // case NODES_REMOVED:
        // fireNodesRemoved(node.getParent().getPathToRoot(), indices,
        // nodes);
        // break;

        case NODE_REMOVED:
            fireNodeRemoved(node.getParent().getPathToRoot(), id, node);
            break;

        // case NODES_CHANGED:
        // fireNodesChanged(node.getParent().getPathToRoot(), indices,
        // nodes);
        // break;

        case NODE_CHANGED:
            fireNodeChanged(node.getParent().getPathToRoot(), id, node);
            break;

        // case NODES_INSERTED:
        // fireNodesInserted(node.getParent().getPathToRoot(), indices,
        // subNodes);
        // break;

        case NODE_INSERTED:
            fireNodeInserted(node.getParent().getPathToRoot(), id, node);
            break;

        default:
            LOGGER.info("Unsupported command type: " + command);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Method addTreeModelListener.
 * 
 * @param listener
 *            TreeModelListener
 * @see javax.swing.tree.TreeModel#addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener)
 */
@Override
public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener listener) {
    LOGGER.info("Adding Listener: " + listener);
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }
}

/**
 * Method removeTreeModelListener.
 * 
 * @param listener
 *            TreeModelListener
 * @see javax.swing.tree.TreeModel#removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener)
 */
@Override
public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener listener) {
    LOGGER.info("Remove Listener: " + listener);
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }
}

/**
 * Tell JTree whether an object in the tree is a leaf or not.
 * 
 * 
 * @param node
 *            Object
 * @return tree if node is a leaf. * @see
 *         javax.swing.tree.TreeModel#isLeaf(Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {
    return ((Node) node).isLeaf();
}

/**
 * Tell JTree how many children a node has.
 * 
 * 
 * @param node
 *            Object
 * @return how many children. * @see
 *         javax.swing.tree.TreeModel#getChildCount(Object)
 */
@Override
public int getChildCount(Object node) {
    int count = ((Node) node).getChildCount();
    LOGGER.info("node='" + node + "', count=" + count);
    return count;
}

/**
 * Fetch any numbered child of a node for the JTree. Our model returns
 * MyNode objects for all nodes in the tree. The JTree displays these by
 * calling the MyNode.toString() method.
 * 
 * @param parent
 * @param index
 * 
 * @return child at the requested index. * @see
 *         javax.swing.tree.TreeModel#getChild(Object, int)
 */
@Override
public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
    Node child = ((Node) parent).getChild(index);
    LOGGER.info("getChild - parent=" + parent + ", index=" + index
            + ", RETURN child=" + child);
    return child;
}

/**
 * Figure out a child's position in its parent node.
 * 
 * @param parent
 *            the parent node
 * @param child
 *            the child node to find index of.
 * @return int
 * @see javax.swing.tree.TreeModel#getIndexOfChild(Object, Object)
 */
@Override
public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
    int index = ((Node) parent).getIndexOfChild((Node) child);
    LOGGER.info("getIndexOfChild - parent=" + parent + ", child=" + child
            + ", RETURN index=" + index);
    return index;
}

/**
 * This method is only invoked by the JTree for editable trees.
 * 
 * @param path
 *            TreePath
 * @param newValue
 *            Object
 * @see javax.swing.tree.TreeModel#valueForPathChanged(TreePath, Object)
 */
@Override
public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object newValue) {
    LOGGER.info("valueForPathChanged path=" + path + ", newValue="
            + newValue);
    Node node = (Node) path.getLastPathComponent();
    node.setName((String) newValue);
}

/**
 * 
 * @return string representation of this object.
 */
public String toString() {
    return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
}
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code on GitHub as per @rolfl suggestions. 1) Node lock is now per node, not static. 2) Listeners don't lead the lock. 3) Replaced weakHashMap with list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### static

What a difference 1 word can make:

> ```
> /** synchronisation lock */
> private static final Object OBJ_LOCK = new Object();
> ```

That 1 word is *'static'*.

In this case, each and every Node shares the exact same OBJ_LOCK instance.

But, that instance is only used to control details inside the actual `Node`.

What you are doing is locking all threads accessing ANY Node, even though you are only changing the details in one node.

Remove the `static`, and change the case to `objLock`, and you should have better thread concurrency.

### Listeners

> ```
> private void fireNodeChanged(ActionEvent e) {
>     LOGGER.info("fireTreeNodeChanged node='" + this + "'");
>     synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
>         for (ActionListener listener : listeners) {
>             listener.actionPerformed(e);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

This code 'leaks' the lock on the listeners. While you are calling the `actionPerformed(e)` events in the listeners you are still locking this `Node` (in fact, every `Node`).

You only need to synchronize the access to the `listeners` data. A simple way to solve this is to:

```
private void fireNodeChanged(ActionEvent e) {
    LOGGER.info("fireTreeNodeChanged node='" + this + "'");
    ActionListener[] tmpListeners = null;
    synchronized (OBJ_LOCK) {
        tmpListeners = listeners.toArray(new ActionListener[listeners.size()]);
    }
    for (ActionListener listener : tmpListeners) {
        listener.actionPerformed(e);
    }

}
```

Now there is not a lock-leak.

This type of problem happens in a few places.

### WeakHashMap

> ```
> listeners = Collections
>         .newSetFromMap(new WeakHashMap<TreeModelListener,Boolean>(32, 0.75f));
> ```

This is not doing what you think it does.

Because the `TreeModelListener` instances are the key to the WeakHashMap, they will never be garbage-collected (the key is a strong-reference....).

Using a WeakHashMap is complicated, and harder to describe than what can easily go here.

Comment: Thank you for the great suggestions. Any thoughts on the bug when new child nodes not showing up after a node has been expanded in UI?  I have updated the code on GitHub. 1) Node lock is now per node, not static. 2) Listeners don't lead the lock. 3) Replaced weakHashMap with list.